# libKMcuda i found this error when i install libKMcuda

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, k-means

while Running setup.py install for libKMCUDA. Gives me error

Complete output from command is:

> /home/hfahad/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-6_fe7y4n/libKMCUDA/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-zufue1e8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake': 'cmake'

Comment: Please present program output, especially error messages, as *block quotes* (mark in the post editor and use "the `“`-button" (or press <Ctrl+Q>)). Give more details about the environment setting up `libKMCUDA` failed in.

Comment: you gotta install `cmake`